# SVG Animation with GSAP, need help to make my animation working with Firefox/Edge

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, gsap

I'm working on a SVG Animation with GSAP/TweenLite. Currently it works fine with Chrome, but it's a nightmare to make it works with Firefox and Edge...

Here is a very simplified version of my animation (To be tested with chrome first):

**CODEPEN**

https://codepen.io/marlburrow/pen/OmyBqq

**HTML**

```
<g class="circle-group circle2" transform="rotate(60, 270, 270) translate(0, -210)">
    <circle class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="9"></circle>
    <circle class="circle-point" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2"></circle>
</g>

<g class="circle-group circle3 " transform="rotate(120, 270, 270) translate(0, -210)">
    <circle class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="9"></circle>
    <circle class="circle-point" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2"></circle>
</g>

<g class="circle-group circle4 " transform="rotate(180, 270, 270) translate(0, -210) ">
    <circle class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="9"></circle>
    <circle class="circle-point" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2"></circle>
</g>

<g class="circle-group circle5 " transform="rotate(240, 270, 270) translate(0, -210)">
    <circle class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="9"></circle>
    <circle class="circle-point" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2"></circle>
</g>

<g class="circle-group circle6 " transform="rotate(300, 270, 270) translate(0, -210)">
    <circle class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="9"></circle>
    <circle class="circle-point" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="2"></circle>
</g>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-animation-base{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}  

.circle-point {
  fill: black;
}

.circle {
  stroke:red;
  fill:transparent;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Get elements
var circle1 = document.querySelector('.circle1');
var circle2 = document.querySelector('.circle2');
var circle3 = document.querySelector('.circle3');
var circle4 = document.querySelector('.circle4');
var circle5 = document.querySelector('.circle5');
var circle6 = document.querySelector('.circle6');
var circleGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.circle-group');

// Place all points at the top of the main circle
TweenLite.set(circleGroups,{rotation: 0, transformOrigin: "center 220"})

// Play circle's rotations
TweenLite.to(circle1, 2, {rotation: 360, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
TweenLite.to(circle2, 2, {rotation: 420, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
TweenLite.to(circle3, 2, {rotation: 480, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
TweenLite.to(circle4, 2, {rotation: 540, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
TweenLite.to(circle5, 2, {rotation: 600, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
TweenLite.to(circle6, 2, {rotation: 660, transformOrigin: "center 220"});
```

Note: Each little circle is initially positionned with one rotation and one translation. I need to inline the initial position in the HTML because I want all circles well positionned even if javascript is disabled.

As you can see, the animation is a disaster on FF and Edge, I'm probably doing it the wrong way.

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks